# App crashes unless UISwitch has been moved once to change which Array is loaded

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiswitch

My app has a UISwitch and depending on the position of the switch the app will choose which array is needed.  If I start my app and go to use it without moving the switch (leaving it on the isOn position) the app will crash. (Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range)

As long as I move it once it will then function as I had hoped. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

var selectedRunesArray = [Rune]()

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var allowReversedRunesSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var allowDuplicateRunesSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    @IBAction func reversedRunesChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if allowReversedRunesSwitch.isOn == true {

            selectedRunesArray = runesIncReversedArray

        } else {
            selectedRunesArray = runesArray
        }

    }

    @IBAction func duplicateRunesChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if allowDuplicateRunesSwitch.isOn == true {



        } else {



        }

    }

}
```

I thought maybe the issue here was that I had started the app off with selectedRunesArray being empty so decided to give it an initial value as follows:

```
var seletcedRunesArray = runesIncReversedArray
```

This stopped the app crashing when you try to use it without moving the switch but now it won't change between the 2 Arrays as I want it to depending on the switch state.

Comment: It crashes? Any error message in console then?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach the error. Edited original message now

Comment: is the IBAction on the valueDidChange? Double check its hooked up. Set a breakpoints and see whats happening. Your are correct setting the array initially as the  IBActions are only called on user interaction,.

Comment: your array empty , you are assigning data on switching, so intialize your array in viewDidLoad

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and you you'll see where the crash occurs. I'm sure you'll see what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reversedRunesChanged` method will not be called until you change state of switch.

so, you just need to define which array you want to load at first time in `viewdidload`. you can either use:

this

```
selectedRunesArray = runesIncReversedArray
```

or

```
selectedRunesArray = runesArray
```

and also you can do it by getting switch state in `viewdidload` method by putting this in `viewdidload`

```
if allowReversedRunesSwitch.isOn == true {

            selectedRunesArray = runesIncReversedArray

} else {
            selectedRunesArray = runesArray
}
```